# Highcharts Spline: Custom chart marker, on a staggered interval, across the plotted line?

Tags: highcharts, marker, spline

I have spline chart that has a varying x axis, with a minimum of 12 months, and a maximum of 36 months. The chart uses custom markers because the design called for it. But the design ALSO calls for the markers to be staggered - such that the marker only appears on every 4th tick across the x axis (I do not mean the ticks across the bottom, but the points on the line, IN the chart).

I have been researching it and the closest thing I've found is a tick density option. That isn't the feature I am looking for.

Imagine this example, where the SUN marker in the spline appears over January, March, June etc (and just a dot or even nothing for the other months).

Does this ring a bell to anyone - or does it bring any ideas to mind, in terms of something I could try?  Is there perhaps a lesser-known feature in highcharts that I ought to use?

Thank you in advance for reading this and for any thoughts!
Evan

Comment: Could you post your code? That might make it easier for us to visualize the problem as I have troubles understanding your exact problem

Answer (score 2):

You can change the marker on individual data points.  You could preprocess the data to add the symbols only on the points you were interested in.

```
var data = [216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  data[i] = {
    x: i,
    y: data[i]
  }
  if (i % 4 == 0) {
    data[i].marker = {
      symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
    };
  }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gqma0mnj/1/